# Compute dim $S$, where $S$ is a subspace of $V_3$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $S$ denote the set of all vectors $(x,y,z)$ in $V_3$ whose components satisfy $x=y=z$. Determine whether $S$ is a subspace of $V_3$. If $S$ is a subspace, compute dim $S$.

I have found that $S$ is a subspace of $V_3$. But I do not know how to compute its dimension. I am working from Apostol Vol 2, and he goes into many theoretical explanations about dimension, but does not ever actually show how to find it. I know the answer is $1$, but why?

Comment: The dimension of a vector space (or a subspace) is the size of the largest possible linearly independent set contained in that space (which is also the size of the smallest possible set that spans the space).  So suppose you have a set containing two different vectors in $S$.  Can that set possibly be linearly independent?  If not, then the dimension must be no larger than $1$.  And showing it's at least $1$ is easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One dimensional,  since $\{\begin {pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}\}$ is a basis.

Comment: To the original poster, you'll want to prove that this one-element set really is a basis, meaning that it's linearly independent (obvious) and that it spans $S$.

Answer (score 0):

Find a basis for $S$ (that is, a set of vectors that are linearly independent and span $S$). The cardinality of this basis is the dimension of $S$. [If you know the answer is $1$, then it suffices to find a single vector that spans $S$.]